# Is it possible to build a chatbot to query data from a DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

I want to make a chatbot (amazon lex) where a user can ask a question and have the bot return a specific value from a column in dynamodb. Is this doable? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Definitely. The Lambda function invoked by Lex can make API calls to DynamoDB. Start by writing the chatbot and have it return a hard-coded value. Once that's working, add the DynamoDB functionality.